# How to prevent Visual Studio 2010 adding large SQL file to my project in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am developing a project in Visual studio 2010 in c++ and c# .till when I added c++ project in solution I always see a SQL Server Compact Edition Database (.sdb) File.It always annoying me

Please anyone help me how to stop creation of this file ?

Comment: Didn't you mean sdf file? That one is meant for the code browsing database. You can safely ignore that file (if you remove it, VS will recreate it)

Comment: But is there anyway to stop VS creating this file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if my guess that you mean sdf and not sdb file is right, you can disable it in "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Text Editor" -> "C/C++" -> "Advanced" -> "Disable Database"

However you will most likely lose the IntelliSense functionality (I can't test it right now). If you don't want this file to be created in the project structure but you wouldn't mind it being somewhere else, you can set the fallback location in the advanced settings mentioned above and set "Always Use Fallback Location" to True.

Comment: Did you test whether that lost the IntelliSense functionality?

Comment: I don't remember, and I have stopped using Visual Studio quite a long time ago, so there's no way I could test it.